# Print all configurations of a 4 x 5 board with 1's and 0's without three 1's in a row or diagonally, while filling as many 1's as possible

Tags: java, algorithm

Clearly it is not ideal to produce 2^20 possible configurations and eliminate from there. I have thought about building the problem up from a corner of the board (Dynamic Programming) but am having trouble with saving all the possible configurations as I go along. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had a similar approach and what I ended up doing is starting in the upper left corner and then went from there with a recursive function in every direction, which still leaves you with some duplicates, but its much faster.

Comment: And what do you exactly mean with having trouble with saving all the possibilities

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to worry about running out of memory. You can bit-pack a single board inside of an int. The total amount of memory for all possible boards used would then be about 5MB. So you shouldn't have any issues just brute forcing the problem.

Remember the golden adage, brute force first, then get smart.

So what you would do is something like this to access the various bits:

```
read_bit(int bit) {
 return (bitpack >> bit) & 0x01;
}

write_bit(int bit, int value) {
 bitpack = (bitpack) | ((value & 0x01) << bit);
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the bit-pack technique?

Comment: @harshwinter69 I included something you can use above. To actually index from 2d do something like (x*row_size) + y